# How can I take the logaritm of a complex?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Through Euler's identity and using $(-1)^x$ I've reached that $\ln(e^{i\pi x}) = \ln(\cos(\pi x)+i\cdot \sin(\pi x))$ but I can not take the left side out of logarithm -since $i\pi x = \ln(\cos (\pi x)+i\cdot \sin(\pi x))$ is simply wrong- to find an expression for x so that I can derive a function for $x^x$. How can I do it?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Remember that $\operatorname{ln}(x)$ and $e^x$ are inverse functions, i.e. $\operatorname{ln}(e^x)=e^{\operatorname{ln}(x)}=x$. Thus $\operatorname{ln}(e^{i\pi x})=i\pi x$

Comment: *$i \pi x = ln\left(cos(\pi x) + i \space sin(\pi x)\right)$ is simply wrong*. What do you mean by that? **What definition for the $ln$ function are you using here**?

Comment: @SergeBallesta for example x values, right side and left side are not equal. I use ln as the natural logarithm. I'm new to the topic and learning it on my own and I'm trying to derive a formula for $x^x$ through Euler's formula and identity but got stuck here.

Comment: The natural logarithm has different definitions when you want to use it as a real or complex function. More exactly you first learn it as a real function ($ln:\mathbb R^∗_+\to \mathbb R$) before learning that you can define it on $\mathbb C^*$

Comment: Please clarify- Are you trying to A. define $x^x$ or B. take the derivative of $x^x$?  B. is typically done using logarithmic differentiation.

Comment: @nickalh I wanted to define $x^x$ for ranges or domains which are not real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see from your comment that what you're really trying to do is define $x^x$. Well, if $x\gt 0$ then you merely use real exponentiation, nothing to it. However, if $x\lt 0$, then the correct derivation based on Euler's formula is:

$x^x=e^{x\operatorname{ln}(x)}=e^{x(\operatorname{ln}(|x|)+i(2k+1)\pi)}=|x|^x(\operatorname{cos}((2k+1)\pi x+i\operatorname{sin}((2k+1)\pi x))$

For all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

This misses the case of $x=0$, of course. Resolving this case depends on which convention you want to follow. Some people define it as $0$, others as $1$, and the rest leave it undefined. Either way, Euler's formula won't help you with that one.

**Added for clarity:** If $x\lt 0$, then $x=(-1)\cdot|x|$. Thus, $x=e^{\operatorname{ln}((-1)\cdot|x|)}$. By the rules of logarithms, $\operatorname{ln}(ab)=\operatorname{ln}(a)+\operatorname{ln}(b)$, so we have that $\operatorname{ln}((-1)\cdot|x|)=\operatorname{ln}(-1)+\operatorname{ln}(|x|)$. By Euler's formula, $\operatorname{ln}(-1)=i(2k+1)\pi$, so we may write $x=e^{\operatorname{ln}((-1)\cdot|x|)}=e^{\operatorname{ln}(|x|)+i(2k+1)\pi}$.

By the rules of exponents, $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$, so we may conclude that $x^x=(e^{\operatorname{ln}((-1)\cdot|x|)})^x=e^{x(\operatorname{ln}(|x|)+i(2k+1)\pi)}=e^{x\operatorname{ln}(|x|)+i(2k+1)\pi x)}$.

By another exponent law, $a^{b+c}=a^ba^c$, so $e^{x\operatorname{ln}(|x|)+i(2k+1)\pi x)}=e^{x\operatorname{ln}(|x|)}e^{i(2k+1)\pi x}$.

As the exponential and natural logarithm functions are the inverse of each other, $e^{x\operatorname{ln}(|x|)}=|x|^x$, and Euler's formula tells us that $e^{i(2k×1)\pi x}=\operatorname{cos}((2k+1)\pi x)+i\operatorname{sin}((2k+1)\pi x)$

so $e^{x\operatorname{ln}(|x|)}e^{i(2k+1)\pi x}=|x|^x(\operatorname{cos}((2k+1)\pi x)+i\operatorname{sin}((2k+1)\pi x))=x^x$

The full chain of equality:

$$x^x=e^{x\operatorname{ln}((-1)\cdot|x|)}=e^{x\operatorname{ln}(|x|)+x\operatorname{ln}(-1)}=e^{x\operatorname{ln}(|x|)+i(2k+1)\pi x}=e^{x\operatorname{ln}(|x|)}e^{i(2k+1)\pi x}=|x|^x(\operatorname{cos}((2k+1)\pi x)+i\operatorname{sin}((2k+1)\pi x)), k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Thank you, this derivation is completely right but can you help me through what transformations you applied through second to last step?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please let me know if anything remains unclear.

Comment: You are a hero, thank you very much. Also by your contributions for x values smaller than 0 it can be said that $x^x$ is equal to $|x|^x*(-1)^x$. But can this be used for complex x values?

Comment: Absolutely! The only caveat of course is that $x\neq 0$. Otherwise, it works.